# ¿Se pueden buscar en el DLE palabras que empiecen o terminen de una determinada manera?

Tags: dle

¿Existe alguna manera de buscar en el [Diccionario de la lengua de la RAE](http://dle.rae.es) palabras que empiecen o terminen de una determinada manera?

Al igual que en Google, Yahoo y demás buscadores puedes utilizar técnicas como:

- *A** (para indicar que buscas algo que empieza con A y a continuación tiene un número ilimitado de caracteres);
- *Ceb** (igual que el anterior pero la palabra empieza con CEB, como resultado obtendrías: cebada, cebar, cebo, cebolla...)

¿Es posible hacer este tipo de búsqueda en el Diccionario de la RAE? ¿Cómo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sí, hay varios criterios de búsqueda en el [Diccionario de la lengua española](http://dle.rae.es/?w=diccionario).

Si pinchas en el campo donde dice «por palabras» al lado del cuadro de búsqueda te dará varias opciones: palabra exacta, empieza por, termina en...

Pongo una imagen con el desplegable abierto:

[image]

Comment: Parece que estaba justo ahí y no lo había visto.

Comment: A mi me pasó  también. Creo que fue @CarlosAlejo en un comentario el que me enseño esa utilidad del diccionario.

Comment: Sí, creo que fue Carlos que me enseñó a mí también.

Comment: Le falta un icono de una flecha a ese desplegable, así la gente sabría que hay algo debajo